# Defined integrals on bounded functions

Tags: integration

I read in an article that when calculating the integral

$\int{p\left( z \right)\frac{\partial w\left( z \right)}{\partial z}}dz$

You'll get this answer: 
$p\left( z \right)w\left( z \right)\left| _{-\infty }^{+\infty } \right.-\int{w\left( z \right)\frac{\partial p\left( z \right)}{\partial z}}dz$

But when evaluating the term
$ p\left( z \right)w\left( z \right)\left| _{-\infty }^{+\infty } \right.$, they say that it disappear because $w(z)$ is bounded.

> Assuming w(z) is bounded, the first term on the right side vanishes

Why is w(z) making $ p\left( z \right)w\left( z \right)\left| _{-\infty }^{+\infty } \right.$ disappear?

In this case: 
$p(z) = e^{(-x^2)}$ and $w(z) = \frac{1}{1+e^{(-x)}}$

*Lande, R., & Arnold, S. J. (1983). The Measurement of selection on correlated characters. Evolution, 37(6), 1210–1226.*

Comment: What is $p(z)$?

Comment: $p(z)$ is a distribution (say Gaussian). $w(z)$ is a function.

Comment: ...well, there is your reasoning. If $w(z)$ is bounded, then $p(z)w(z)$ is totally dependent on the decay of $p(z)$ which dies at $-\infty$ and $+\infty$.

Comment: I don't understand this: "then p(z)w(z) is totally dependent on the decay of p(z) which dies at −∞ and +∞". Is it because w(z) is bounded because of p(z)?

Comment: Sorry, is $w(z)$ a bounded function? I am assuming it must be or else $p(z)w(z)$ can explode around $\pm \infty$.

Comment: If $w(z)$ is bounded, let's say $||w(z)||\leq M$, then
$$
||p(z)w(z)||\leq M||p(z)||
$$
If $z\to \infty$, then $M||p(z)||\to 0$. Similarly for $z\to-\infty$.

Comment: Indeed, w(z) is bounded. But I don't get why taking the norm of the function would give you "M". What that means to multiply this M by the Gaussian distribution? Why would it tend to 0?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67506/discussion-between--and-m-beausoleil).